# Inserting post terms into DB separately

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I am trying to add tags to my videos as terms and the problem is if i have more tags for one video they are stored in one variable and passed to the DB as a group, what i need to have is that every tag gets inserted to the db separately

Right now its like this:
Example :

```
$tags = #tag1 #tag2 #tag3
wp_insert_term( $tags, 'post_tag');
```

In the db it looks like

```
term_id           name              slug
   1        #tag1 #tag2 #tag3  tag1-tag2-tag3
```

and I would need it to be like this

```
term_id           name              slug
   1              #tag1             tag1
   2              #tag2             tag2
   3              #tag3             tag3
```

Comment: So `explode` tag string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress doesn't know what's your intention, so

```
$tags = '#tag1 #tag2 #tag3'
```

is actually one variable. So, say it different, try the snippet below

```
$tags = array('#tag1', '#tag2', '#tag3', '#tag4', '#tag5');
foreach($tags as $tag){
    wp_insert_term(trim($tag), 'post_tag'); // just in case, use trim() for cleaning
}
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/Olb8Fy)

If you'd like to use `explode()`, be sure to clean each value using `trim()`; or better said be sure you don't have an empty string.

Comment: @Prashant Why the user should build a string? If actually he/she doesn't need it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$tags = "#tag1 #tag2 #tag3";
$tagsArray = explode(" ", $tags);
foreach($tagsArray as $tag)
{
    wp_insert_term( $tag, 'post_tag'); 
}
```

Comment: By the way, using `explode()` just the way do did isn't good and safe enough. Juts image if the user has something like this `$tags = "#tag1  #tag2 #tag3 ";` end you'll end up with five values added into database.